# Updating custom dimension on transaction

Tags: google-analytics

I have an ecommerce site that uses Universal analytics to track orders.
when an order is placed, I would like to track the purchase with a custom dimension, e.g. 'State = placed'

If an order is later completed, I would like the transaction to be updated so that the custom dimension goes from 'placed' to 'completed'. In this way, I can filter my reports on GA based on the state of the order.

Is it possible to update the custom dimension on a transaction using the api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be wonderful if somebody could prove me wrong, but right now I'd have to say no, that is not possible. The relevant GA feature would be [data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6064694?vid=1-635778374428468216-2135761512&rd=1), but the only import that works on a transaction level is [refund data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014861?ref_topic=6065609&vid=1-635778374428468216-2135761512) and apparently that does not allow to update custom dimensions. A possible workaround might be to record an dummy item "pending" with a one cent value and refund this after the transaction has cleared. That way you could segment out the difference between pending and fullfilled orders.